# What is this pattern at the back of a violin called?

Tags: violin

I am somehow under the impression that there is a name for such pattern in the picture but I am not sure.

How does such a pattern impact violin acoustically comparing to e.g. tiger maple?

[image]

Comment: The fact that both sides are pretty well mirror images of each other is called *bookmatched*.

Comment: _What_ pattern? The waist (c bout), the joint down the center, the wood grain, the convex back?

Comment: ... or maybe the colouring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you see here is mostly just the grain of the wood. High value instruments tend to use strongly *figured* or *flamed* sycamore instead of plain one. This is a thing where the grain does not grow straight, but in "waves". Such wood is much harder to work with, as during carving and planing you can rip out parts of the flame and when bending it is more prone to snapping. Also this is a very rare thing and occurs randomly in wood. So strongly figured wood is actually quite rare and thus very expensive. (There’s also different kinds of  figuring that are occasionally used for instrument making like bird’s eye).

So the real reason why such a wood is chosen is due to it being a high value wood and aesthetically pleasing. But there is not much of an acoustic benefit to figured wood, it’s mostly optical. One *could* argue that the grain of the back and the sides influences their vibrations, but then, those do not matter much (and even if this would differ for each instrument, as no two figured woods are the same). The important thing is the vibrations of the top, which is why the top is made from different wood (fir) of very straight and even grain.

Of course while the back does not *directly* influence the sound it is still to some extent a measure for the value of the instrument. A cheaply made instrument will use cheap woods and at the same time probably not sound as good as an expensive one which uses expensive woods, merely for the sake of being fancy. This does not mean that an instrument made from plain wood necessarily **has** to be cheaper made and sound worse than one made from figured wood.

One thing you notice on such instruments made of cheaper wood is that the varnish tends to be a bit "patchy". This is a way to make the back look less plain than the woods actually is.